# Can grep be used for searching files with some string in their names?

Tags: files, grep, search

I understand that `grep` can only be used for searching for files which contain a string in their content.

Can it be used for searching for files with a string in their names? I read the manpage, and don't think so.

Also Is `grep` pronounced as [gri:p] or [grep] (in IPA notation)? I read it as the former.

Comment: The *e* sound is short: http://www.pronuncian.com/Lessons/default.aspx?Lesson=96 as in "bed", "said", "dead" -- not long (which would be `greep`).

Comment: `grep` is only able to search for patterns. You have to use other tools to generate the data which is then fed to grep to search for these patterns.

Answer (score 10):

You seem to be looking for `find`:

```
find . -type f -name "*foo*"
```

would look for file names containing `foo` in the name in the current directory and subdirectories.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*foo*"
```

would look for file names containing `foo` only in the current directory.

Comment: thanks. I know `find` can do it. I wonder if `grep` can do it? I don't think so, but someone said it could.

Comment: @Tim `grep` _by itself_ can't.  `grep` can if you pipe the list of files to it :)

Comment: Is it a good way? How do you say `grep`?

Comment: @Tim Here you go: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/grep

Comment: @Tim You have to understand that `grep` only looks at content, whether by opening files or in standard input. If you want grep to look at filenames, you have to put file names in its content. Either store the list of filenames in a file or pass it to grep on its standard input. Neither way is recommended - it is like using a hammer on a screw, i.e. wrong tool for wrong job.

Comment: @jw: thanks. how do you output all the list of filenames under a directory? Including those under all sub directories, and sub sub .... directories.

Comment: @Tim `find . -type f`

Comment: It makes no sense to have two different tools for the same thing.  UNIX philosophy is »one job one tool«.  If your job is finding a file, the tool is `find`.  If it's finding something inside a file, it's `grep`.

Comment: `UNIX philosophy is »one job one tool` -- shell designers beg to differ

Answer (score 5):

Use `find` to generate a list of filenames and then `grep` to parse them:

```
find . | grep 'stack[oO0]verfl[oO0]w'
```

Unless you have a filesystem where the list of filenames is itself a file I don't see how `grep` can do that alone.

Comment: But you should add that `find . -name 'stack[oO0]verfl[oO0]w'` would be a bit more efficient, as it does not need two processes running. (There is a small difference, as the `grep` variant will match the complete path name, not only the filename.)

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, you can use `grep` itself to generate the names of (non-empty) files in the current directory and spawn another `grep` to look for the ones you want:

```
grep -l . * 2>/dev/null | grep 'your_pattern'
```

The `2>/dev/null` is needed because `grep` will complain if you ask it to look in a directory without supplying the `-r` option.

*Caveat emptor*: this will perform poorly with files that have newlines in their name and will ignore dot (hidden) files and empty files. [`find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129511/26909) is the right way to go, here.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if that would be useful, and I can't comment so...

`ls | grep [regexPattern]`

*exempli gratia*: search for files that initiate with the letter 'p':

`ls | grep ^p`

And can be mixed in a lot of different way(with regex) to search what you want to find, I remember that I read an [article](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) that says to not parse the output of the ls, so be careful.

Comment: For finding files by different criteria (amongst them its name) there's been something invented called, well… `find`.

Comment: Yea, it's a better way than feeding the grep with a ls(parsing ls at the same time), thank you! :)

Comment: @AndreasWiese `ls | grep` is a bit simpler to type than `find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name`

Comment: Yes indeed, but find is better, i just came up with this option of parsing the ls with the grep :p

Comment: @RafaelNunes Better in what way? `ls | grep` is perfectly fine

Comment: @BroSlow, have a look at the article.

Comment: @RafaelNunes I've read it before. There really isn't an issue with piping, unless there are files with newlines, which is pretty silly to protect against. There is an issue with parsing ls with arguments, or doing `for file in $(ls)`, but that's for a variety of other reasons.

Comment: Yea, it can be used to achieve what you want, but when I was scripting in shell, something wrong happened with parsing ls, and it was not the new line... So you have to be careful in what you are using it...

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, no. Grep cannot search via the names of files, it can only search through textual data as it's presented to it. So you basically have 2 options with `grep`.

You can either have it search through a list of files that you present to it, and `grep` will open each of these files in turn, looking for the pattern that you've instructed it to look for, or you can feed it a stream of data via STDIN.

In either case `grep` cannot look at the "meta data" around the source of its input (STDIN or files), only their contents.

Answer (score 1):

`GNU grep` has an option to only `--include` specific filenames, but you still have to provide `grep` with a pattern to search for. For example

```
grep -r --include '*.txt' PATTERN .
```

will recursively traverse the current working directory and print any lines matching `PATTERN` within files ending in `.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` with `grep` :

for example :

```
┌─ oneofone@Oa [~/c/g/s/g/O/cleanml] (master|●4✚3)                                                                
└──➜ find -type f -name '*.go' -exec grep -n package '{}' +
./html/doc.go:1:package html
./html/element.go:1:package html
./scanner/tree.go:1:package scanner
./scanner/tokenizer.go:1:package scanner
./main.go:1:package main
```

Or just `grep` : `grep package **/*pat* *pat*`

Or you could use [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/) if you're searching for code : `ack package --type=go`

Comment: `**/*pat* *pat*`. Isn't the second `*pat*` redundant with globstar on?

Comment: I'm not very sure, I don't use that much.